# Show last database entry for user

Tags: php, mysql

This is kindda of a hard one.
The whole story: I have a page where users register and login. in database they get a `member_id` value (auto increasing) this database is "`users`". So when the user wnats to order something the data of the item and his `member_id` get into another database let's say "`orders`". In this database is sotred the info about he product and his member_id. So when the user would hit the button check-out he would have to come to a page where his LAST added item would be displayed sorted by his member_id

So something like, show me the last item entry for this user.

I don't know if the current session that i am using `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` must be compaird to the `member_id` table in the database to identify this users last entry.

To be honest i have no idea how i should do this.

I hope this wasn't to confusing... :)

Edit: Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders ( 
  order_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
  Items text NOT NULL, 
  member_id text NOT NULL )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please show us your code .

Comment: Do you have a primary key in `orders` table ?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia  you mean the code of the page or the code procesing file?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i just have 3 colums, order_numb (auto increasment), item (name of the item) and member_id (the id of the member)

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: @NarendraSisodia This would probably confuse alot of people since half of the code is not in english. :/

Comment: Please show us your database structure for your table `orders`. Either in your question or via http://sqlfiddle.com/ and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @IkoTikashi
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
`order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Items` text NOT NULL,
  `member_id` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: You are talking about DATABASE 'users' and DATABASE 'orders'. Just to clarify: did you mean table instead of database? 'users' and 'orders' are tables in the same database, right?

Comment: @IkoTikashi Yes. DB name is shop and here i have "users" and "orders". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure for your table `orders` is "wrong", `member_id` should ideally have the same settings like in your `users` table, `int(11)` I guess. So your table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders ( 
  order_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
  Items text NOT NULL, 
  member_id int(11) NOT NULL )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As for selecting a users orders latest item, try this SQL:

`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE member_id = [XYZ] ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1;` similar to other answers here. Replace `[XYZ]` with a member_id. If that doesn't work in your code, make sure to try this query in phpMyAdmin (or CLI etc.).

Comment: I don't get this. I have changed my DB and still nothing is working. So you are saying:
`SELECT * FROM orders WHERE member_id = [member_id] ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1;` ???

Comment: Nope, `[XYZ]` should be an integer (1,2,3 etc.), in your case probably your `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']`, so like `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE member_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . "  ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: I thought that also at first but when i tried it nothing was showing up.
Here is what i got:
`<HTML code>`
`<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE member_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] . " ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
?>`
`<HTML code>`

Comment: Print `$sql` out right after that code and see if it's a valid SQL query.

Comment: i dont know how to print out. :$
`<?php print $sql ?>` ?

Comment: Ugh ;) Just `echo $sql` before the `?>`

Comment: Ok, this is getting a little out of hand. What do you mean "nothing came out", it should've printed your $sql. Are you 100% sure you have data in your table `orders`. If you have phpMyAdmin at hand, take a look at the table. If there is data, make sure your `$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']` is actually a valid `member_id` from your table users.

Comment: I mean that like the page loaded normaly like always without any sql statement. There is data coming to the DB orders when is hit the Add to Cart button. All tables have data in them. The order DB and the member DB have the actuall valid user ID.

Comment: I got it working but i have i like this now:
`$sql = "SELECT id, item FROM orders WHERE member_id = " .$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']. " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";`

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can take member id in session (if its not) and than you can just get last entry of this member from `order`(if member_id is present in order table) table by using the following mysql query

```
$sql=mysql_query("select max(`id`) from `orders` where member_id='".$_SESSION['member_id']."'");
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's not showing the last item entry in fact it's not showing anything.

Comment: just edited my answer try it ...remember field that i have taken is only a example you have to modify it.. and i am thinking that you have taken a member_id column in order table and an id column which is auto increment

Comment: Table name is `orders`, not `order`.

Comment: @vivek i don't know why but nothing is showing up. :/
What is the `max('id')` for?

Comment: ok no problem .. just echo query and see is there any error if not then run query in phpmyadmin and see the results

Comment: can you show your database table form where you want to fetch records

Comment: @vivek
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders ( 
  order_id int(11) NOT NULL, 
  Items text NOT NULL, 
  member_id text NOT NULL )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

Comment: based on your table structure....select max(`order_id`) from `orders` where `member_id`='".$_SESSION['member_id']."'" its working fine at my end

Comment: it works for you make my answer right tick so other can get help easily

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last entry for the user from `orders` table you can use the following as

```
select * from orders
where 
member_id = ?
order by order_num desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch max id from table where id would be auto increment.
then fetch the record of table for that id :

```
$no="select max(id) from table";
$no1=mysql_fetch_row($no);
$sql="select * from table where id=$no1[0]";
$a=mysql_fetch_row($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `orderby`

```
select * from orders where  member_id = 'Member ID' order by order_num desc limit 0,1
```